Allow specific ip addresses only
At the moment any device (any internet protocol addresses) can log on to my ZTE wireless modem.
How can I specify a list of internet protocol addresses devices that are allowed access to it?

Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

"How can I specify a list of internet protocol addresses devices that are allowed access to it?" - You don't; You just secure it with a username and strong cryptographically secure password.

where are the IPs you are trying to lock down? are they on the Internet, or are they part of your local network (or both)?

Some wireless routers allow MAC address whitelists. Because it is the wireless router itself handing out IP addresses (most likely) you won't accomplish what you may be trying to accomplish by limiting IP addresses. You should look through the wireless config options on your device and see whether it allows you to whitelist or block MAC addresses.

Does this answer your question? How to add additional MAC addresses to wireless MAC address filter in ZTE modem?
